# Keras: What does Conv2DTranspose exactly do?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm a beginner to Keras/Tensorflow. I think I have a basic understanding what Conv2DTranspose  generally does. In detail I struggle.

Therefore I wrote an extremly simple example. This example shall show, how the values in a source-matrix, the kernel and a target-matrix are exactly connected:

- 5x5 source-matrix has one 1 - rest is 0s
- 3x3 kernel is enumerated by 1-9
- stride is 2,2

```
import numpy as np
import keras as keras 

X = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
X = X.reshape((5, 5, 1))
model = keras.models.Sequential()
layer = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', input_shape=(5, 5, 1))
model.add(layer)
weights = [np.array([ [[[1]],[[2]],[[3]]],
                      [[[4]],[[5]],[[6]]],
                      [[[7]],[[8]],[[9]]]
                    ], dtype="float32"), 
           np.array([0.], dtype="float32")]
layer.set_weights(weights)
y = model.predict(X).reshape((10, 10))
print(y)
```

The result ist

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2.]
 [4. 5. 7. 8. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

- Very suprising: the 9 in the lower-right-position of the kernel does not even appear in the result
- Also suprising: Positions of 1-9 in relation to the 1 in the source

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Your `X` is not shaped correctly. It needs to be `reshape((1, 5, 5, 1))`; you always need a batch axis. It's a bit unfortunate that your example even runs at all, IMHO it should crash due to shape mismatch. With your code, I suppose it is interpreted as a batch with 5 elements, and a width x height of 5 x 1 (and 1 channel). That is why you get strange results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @xdurch0. Great answer.

After reshaping X with
`X = X.reshape((1,5, 5, 1))`
I got something I'd expect:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 4. 5. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 7. 8. 9. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I just post the proper answer, since others also may ask "What does Conv2DTranspose exactly do"